# Looking to filter based on struct value that is nested in array

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Table:

```
id list
1. [{A: Test, B: Test2},{A:Non, B:Non2}]
2. [{A: Rand, B: Rand2},{A:Temp, B:Temp2}]
3. [{A: Val, B: Val2},{A:Temp, B:Temp2}]
```

I want to filter this table for rows that have `A` equal to `Temp`

So the remaining table would look like this:

```
id list
2. [{A: Rand, B: Rand2},{A:Temp, B:Temp2}]
3. [{A: Val, B: Val2},{A:Temp, B:Temp2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`any_match`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?#any_match) function and a [lambda expression](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/lambda.html) to look inside the arrays:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE any_match(t.list, e -> e.A = 'Temp')
```